# How to properly sync code with svn iOS XCode

Tags: ios, svn, xcode8

I am new to iOS development. I am using Xcode 8.1. I am trying to add svn to my project. I was able to add it,code is also getting updated. But when two users edit the same line in code it is not showing any clashes, the latest code is getting updated . Am I making any mistake?. What are the other alternatives?